# Tentacle gets out of mesh

Tags: mesh, armature

Hello Blender community,

So I'm facing a weird problem where the tentacle/arm/extremity gets outside of the mesh when the armature moves it. I've attached a couple of pictures here below. I'm trying to look for some functionality to lock the tentacle in the main body mesh. When I see other tutorials, the arms never leave the main mesh. What could be causing my model to act this way? The movement seems decently realistic as long as the armature doesn't move too far from the mesh. But once I do, the tentacle actually gets detached from the main mesh. Would appreicate any help. Thanks!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: the base bone of the tentacle is not attached/parented to some other bone linked to the "body" ?

Comment: It's not, no :s but I just did that and now all the legs get separated :/

Comment: for me, hard to say without the blend file. You can upload it here if you want http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1528" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1528/) Ok just did

Comment: to me, your bones chain is inverted. The first bone may start near the body (on top) and the last may be at the tentacle extremity. And the current first bone (named "bone") could be parented to an additional central bone (all the tentacles may be parented like that) which could drive the whole mesh.

Comment: additionally, I suggest that the tentacles be linked (at the mesh level) to the body. If you dont do that, it may be painful to do the rig without having any break between the body and tentacles (but this is a choice)

Comment: Ok, I tried making a new bone chain with the bone at the top being the first one in the chain, but it still didn't make a difference :s I also tried parenting the main bone but the mesh got distorted in some weird way. I just want to find some constraing that would keep the mesh together. In all the tutorials I watched, this was a given. I don't know why my tentacle shoots off like that :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, your bone chain is inverted.

You can remark that when you move the bottom bone, all come with it, but when you take the top bone it is constrained by the bottom bone :

[image]

So you can simply invert the situation (apply rotations and scale to your mesh before that). I have separated a tentacle in order you see well :

- Select the armature
- Go to edit mode
- Select all the bones
- And rotate it 180°
- Adjust the Z location
- Go back to object mode
- Reparent the tentacle

[image]

For a more complete model, add another "top parent bone". This will allow to bring all your tentacles together and also the jelly body.

[image]

The blend file : [image]

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you are welcome @Xiggi... have a nice jelly fish !

Comment: I have a question. How did you add make all the bones part of the same armature? I can't seem to do so using the outliner menu. I want to add bones to the big tentacles and add them to the main "parent bone" like the smaller tentacles are parented.

Comment: Starting from the bones of one tentacle, I simply duplicate them. Two possibilities : 1/ duplicate the armature in object mode and join them all (ctrl+J) 2/ duplicate the armature in edit mode. This is nearly the same. Next attach the "top bones" to the parent center (just set it as parent).